# Arduino IDE crash when I connect Blend Micro

Tags: arduino-ide

I recently bought [Blend Micro](http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/) and I am setting up Arduino IDE to start using it, but after installing the required libraries and the Blend Micro drivers, the IDE suddenly crashes without any visible error whenever I plug the blend micro to my PC. If it is already plugged in, the ide won't even start up. This was not happening before I installed the drivers. I don't know if it's relevant but blend micro was connected to my pc during the drivers installation. I have already looked for a way to solve this on Google without relevant results.

I am using Windows 10 with Arduino IDE 1.6.12

I would really appreciate any help with my problem, thank you in advance.

Comment: Reboot the PC, try an other one, try a different USB port, try uninstalling the IDE and reinstalling it...

Comment: I have already tried all those 3 things and they did not work...

Comment: I count 4 things there...

Comment: Yes, I did all 4, the 3 was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to my problem was to download [the latest arduino hourly build](https://www.arduino.cc/download.php?f=/arduino-nightly-windows.zip). There is probably a bug in the stable version that has been solved in the hourly build.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to run the arduino from the consolle, on windows digit cmd on the search bar and the command promp program should appear.

Well, then you should navigate in out arudiono folder: digit `cd "XXX"` where XXX is the arduino executable location (something like c:/program files/blabla), you can copy paste it from the folder explorer.

then write `arduino_debug.exe` and you should see on the terminal the error appear; with that we may find the issue.

Comment: arduino_debug.exe may provide more information.

Comment: @per1234 fixed, thanks, I use win only to play so im a bit rust on that side xD